# Why small $C^2$-perturbation of the sphere is a convex hypersurface?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Why small $C^2$-perturbation of the sphere is a convex hypersurface? In fact, I don't know what is   $C^2$-perturbation. Whether it mean the position vector $F(x,t)$ is $C^2$ about $t$? But in my view, this is not enough to show the small $C^2$-perturbation of the sphere is a convex hypersurface.

This question is origin from first line of 3th page of [Blow-up of the mean curvature at the first singular time of the mean curvature flow](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.1133.pdf).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The curvature depend on second derivatives. Since the sphere has positive constant curvature, a C^2-small deformation has also positive curvature, and a compact surface with strictly positive curvature is convex.

Comment: Try with the circle it is the same. Its curvature (2nd derivatives) is $1$ so perturbating the 2nd derivative gives a curvature $\approx 1\pm \epsilon$

Comment: @reuns  So, the $C^2$ perturbation means perturbating the 2nd derivative ?

Comment: Not only the 2nd ones but also the 1st and 0th, continuously and within some $\epsilon$-bounds. But the definition really depends on what you need it for. Try to visualize ways to perturbate a (closed) smooth curve, and adapt it to hypersurfaces. You might need to consider local charts from the original to the perturbated one.